# Plot Percentile Indication in R / GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, quantile, horizontal-line

I have a basic plot of a two column data frame (x = "Periods" and y = "Range").

[image]

```
library (ggplot2)
qplot (Periods, Range, data=twocoltest, color=Periods, size = 3,) + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.2))
```

I am trying to add a horizontal line at each period below which lie 90% of all the observations for that period.  (It doesn't have to be a horizontal line, any visual indication per period would suffice).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have never used `ggplot` but this page looks like it might be helpful: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_summary.html . Also, you can get the 90% percentile with `quantile(x,probs=0.9)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alrighty, I've read the ggplot help, and here's a go:

```
# example data 
twocoltest <- data.frame(Periods=rep(1:3,each=3),Range=1:9)

library(ggplot2)
c <- qplot (Periods, Range, data=twocoltest, color=Periods, size = 3,) + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.2))
q90 <- function(x) {quantile(x,probs=0.9)}

c + stat_summary(fun.y=q90, colour="red", geom="crossbar", size = 1, ymin=0, ymax=0)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also try adding `geom = "line"` and `aes(group = 1)` (and removing `ymin` and `ymax`) for something possibly a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: @joran - i'm lost. At what point do I add `aes(group=1)`? I just end up with a line joining the 90%ile at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much. thelatemail's example does what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that a single line connecting the 90th %-iles might look a bit nicer, that's all.

Comment: One last question, I can add additional quantile lines successfully e.g.,  qz <- function(x) {z <- quantile(x,probs=c(0.5, 0.84, 0.97))} but I haven't figured out how to give those quantile lines unique colors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I think I'm challenged at a fundamental level :-(